Sampler is not failed even when JSR223 Assertion is failed
I'm executing negative scenario for Jmeter API automation,
Scenario: Running negative scenario and validation following,
Status Code = 400
Validation Message = X
Output :
Status Code:400
Validation Message = Y
JSR22 Assertion failed but not the main sampler,

I'm using below code in JSR223 Assertion,
def errorvalue = vars.getObject("errorvalue_1")
log.info("Value of Json Response Error Message is ::"+errorvalue)

def experror = vars.get("ErrorMsg")
log.info("Error value is ::"+experror)

if(errorvalue.toString().equals(experror.toString())){
 
    log.info("Error Message is matched")
    AssertionResult.setFailure(false)
     AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Error Message is matched")
}else{
    log.info("Error Message is not matched")
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
     AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Error Message is not matched")
}

Please help me to make it fail main sampler.

Add prev.setSuccessful(false) if you want to mark the Sampler(s) in the JSR223 Assertion's scope as failed.
prev stands for previous SampleResult, see JavaDoc for all available functions and Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.
